# SQL Recursive Update Query for Creating Network Diagram/Gantt Chart

Tags: sql-server

Need below result on the basis of below table structure.

**Result**: 
ProjectUID  TaskUID TaskName    MastID  MastName    ChildID ChildName   LNK LnkType Level
1   1   T1  1   T1  NULL    NULL    P   NULL    1
1   6   T6  6   T6  NULL    NULL    S   NULL    2
1   1   T1  1   T1  6   T6  S   SS  1
1   2   T2  2   T2  6   T6  S   SS  3
1   5   T5  5   T5  6   T6  S   FS  1
1   1   T1  1   T1  2   T2  S   SS  1
1   2   T2  2   T2  1   T1  P   SS  3
1   3   T3  3   T3  1   T1  P   FS  4
1   4   T4  4   T4  1   T1  P   SS  1
1   6   T6  6   T6  1   T1  P   SS  2
1   5   T5  5   T5  4   T4  P   SS  1
1   3   T3  3   T3  2   T2  P   FS  4
1   5   T5  5   T5  2   T2  P   SF  1
1   6   T6  6   T6  2   T2  P   SS  2
1   2   T2  2   T2  5   T5  S   SF  3
1   4   T4  4   T4  5   T5  S   SS  1
1   1   T1  1   T1  4   T4  S   SS  1
1   3   T3  3   T3  4   T4  S   FF  4
1   4   T4  4   T4  3   T3  P   FF  1
1   5   T5  5   T5  4   T4  P   SS  1
1   1   T1  1   T1  2   T2  S   SS  1
1   1   T1  1   T1  3   T3  S   FS  1
1   2   T2  2   T2  3   T3  S   FS  3
1   6   T6  6   T6  5   T5  P   FS  2
1   4   T4  4   T4  3   T3  P   FF  1
1   6   T6  6   T6  5   T5  P   FS  2
1   5   T5  5   T5  4   T4  P   SS  1
1   1   T1  1   T1  2   T2  S   SS  1
1   6   T6  6   T6  5   T5  P   FS  2
1   6   T6  6   T6  5   T5  P   FS  2

**Table structure along with sample data**:

Create Table #NetworkDiagram
(
ProjectUID VarChar(200),
TaskUID VarChar(200),
TaskName VarChar(200),
MastID VarChar(200),
MastName VarChar(200),
ChildID VarChar(200),
ChildName VarChar(200),
LNK VarChar(1),
LNKType VarChar(2)
)
Insert Into #NetworkDiagram
(
ProjectUID,
TaskUID,
TaskName,
MastID,
MastName,
ChildID,
ChildName,
LNK,
LNKType
)
Insert Into A
(ProjectUID,TaskUID,Taskname,MastID,MastName,ChildID,ChildName, LNK,LNKType)
Values
('1','1','T1','1','T1','2','T2','S','SS'),
('1','1','T1','1','T1','3','T3','S','FS'),
('1','1','T1','1','T1','4','T4','S','SS'),
('1','1','T1','1','T1','6','T6','S','SS'),
('1','1','T1','1','T1',NULL,NULL,'P',NULL),
('1','2','T2','2','T2','1','T1','P','SS'),
('1','2','T2','2','T2','3','T3','S','FS'),
('1','2','T2','2','T2','5','T5','S','SF'),
('1','2','T2','2','T2','6','T6','S','SS'),
('1','3','T3','3','T3','1','T1','P','FS'),
('1','3','T3','3','T3','2','T2','P','FS'),
('1','3','T3','3','T3','4','T4','S','FF'),
('1','4','T4','4','T4','1','T1','P','SS'),
('1','4','T4','4','T4','3','T3','P','FF'),
('1','4','T4','4','T4','5','T5','S','SS'),
('1','5','T5','5','T5','2','T2','P','SF'),
('1','5','T5','5','T5','4','T4','P','SS'),
('1','5','T5','5','T5','6','T6','S','FS'),
('1','6','T6','6','T6','1','T1','P','SS'),
('1','6','T6','6','T6','2','T2','P','SS'),
('1','6','T6','6','T6','5','T5','P','FS'),
('1','6','T6','6','T6',NULL,NULL,'S',NULL)

Comment: can you throw expected output of same example ?

Comment: Your output doesn't seem to match your data at all...

Comment: It does. I dry run the logic several time and used excel as well to see the result